# How to set up tablix to show groups of rows based on filter?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to create a report as in the attached image and I am not sure how to go about it. It has to be one tablix, or at least appear as one when exported to excel.  I have one dataset that has discriminating column, 'Type' and I need to group rows based on that type. When one group of rows finishes, I need a row with caption and formatting that spans two columns. Header has 'Code' and 'Description' Column and rows should bind to those columns from dataset. Is this possible with SSRS?

Now that David confirmed that it is doable, can somebody explain how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do this with SSRS.  This is a fairly garden-variety use case but if you are not familiar with SSRS you may find it to be somewhat obtuse in the way you are made to go about this -- in many ways it is not very intuitive.